# org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint takes more memory

Tags: memory-usage, tomcat6, memory-leak

org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint takes more memory as per new relic Thread profiler. The memory utilization never reduced even in idle time. It seems there is a memory leak in this class. Could you please help me to debug little more?

[image: Screenshot from NewRelic]

Comment: Try taking a thread dump to get a list of all the threads running on your server. Windows: `ctrl + break`, Linux `kill -3 <pid>`

Comment: We did Thread Profiling in new relic and shows active threads. Even in idle time the above class takes much memory. Attaching the screenshot